# How to build AND Gate using transistors?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, logic-gates

I am very new to electronics field. Especially to the digital electronics.

I am trying to make an AND gate circuit using transistors, switches and LED.
I have tried the below circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6STyq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But there is a problem when simulating this circuit.

```
SW1     |     SW2     |     LED
OFF     |     OFF     |     OFF
OFF     |     ON      |     80%
ON      |     OFF     |     20%
ON      |     ON      |     100%
```

As you can see that above mentioned truth table is not AND Gate but it looks more like OR Gate. So, what is my mistake??

Comment: Put pull down resistors on the base of each transistor - perhaps about 10k. I also see no point for R3.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have tried to do that but still I don't get the perfect output. I mean When SW1 and SW2 are off LED is OFF, When SW1 is ON and SW2 is OFF LED is OFF, But when SW1 is OFF and SW2 is ON LED is ON.

Comment: You'll probably have better results with the LED "above" the transistors (on the collector of `Q1`), rather than driving it with an emitter follower. Also add a fairly strong pull down on their bases to ensure offness. In your current configuration, as soon as `SW2` is on, some of `Q2`'s base current will flow through the LED and illuminate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what is my mistake??

The mistake you have made is that current passing through SW2 will pass through the base and out of the emitter and then through the LED. A BJT has a base-emitter junction that is a forward biased diode.

If you used MOSFETs instead you wouldn't have this problem because the gate is insulated from the source.

Comment: After your answer, I have tried to use 2N7000 (MOSFET) instead of 2N2222 (BJT). But now no matter I have my switches ON or OFF, the LED glows. Why is it doing so??

Comment: Because you need pull down resistors on each gate to ground. When the switch opens the gate source voltage remains because of capacitance.

Comment: I have also tried that right now, but still it does not make any difference

Comment: I should mention that, I have removed R3 and interchanged the position of R4 and LED.

Comment: Maybe you have the mosfets incorrectly connected - it sounds like a source:drain reversal to me. Middle pin is gate of course but some fets are different to others.

Comment: I gave positive supply to drain and negative supply to the source. Is it correct?

Comment: I think Drain as Collector and Source as Emitter. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's correct but did you check the pin outs from the data sheet?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still no clue of what's going on here. I have also used circuit simulation. There I get it right. But When I use the same principles for building actual circuit, I have problems.

Comment: Here is the live circuit simulation https://circuits.io/circuits/3777448-the-unnamed-circuit/edit

Comment: I don't need to see it to know it should work. It sounds like you have somehow implemented it incorrectly - what happens if you short gate to source on one of the MOSFETs? No use throwing the switch on the one that is shorted because the signal will pass to the source - I'm interested to see if the LED turns off.

Comment: I have got it. The datasheet I was looking at was wrong. I mean it shown wrong pinouts. Then I refered to Motorola datasheet and there I find the correct Pinout diagram. Thank you for your help. I will accept the answer after implementing new circuit by using the Motorola datasheet. Thank you once again.

Comment: You'll never do that again LOL.

Comment: I have implemented new circuit and its working great. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

The Forward biasing of Q2's BE junction when SW2 pressed, is causing the LED to glow.

You can try below,

1. Relocate the diode D1 between +ve terminal of the power supply & collector of Q1 (i.e D1's Anode is connected to +9V & Cathode connected to Q1's collector).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if more logic is being driven, rather than say an LED, then the output of the gate is inverted.

Answer (score 1):

As colin__s already stated in the comments you can best move the led to the collector of the NPN transistor. When using an NPN transistor as a switch, you can best use it to pull-down current (connect the emitter to the lowest potential and the switched element to the collector).

Futhermore an LED usually can handle a maximum of 20mA, so I would increase the series resistor to 470 (so you get a lower current, (9V-1.6V)/470 = 15mA)). With the 300 ohm resistor your current would be >20mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9PAyB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this way the current flowing trough the base-emitter junction doesn't light the LED when only one of the switches is on.